# Is there any library popular in Python to monitor Linux/Unix system?

Tags: python, linux, monitoring, monitor

In erlang, thare is a os_mon module responsible for monitoring system, but I haven't found the library like that for python,is there any?
thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Two ways of doing this:

1. Use `subprocess` to call another process that can get this information for you.
2. Use [PyMeter](http://pymeter.sourceforge.net/). Does what you want easily.

Comment: I want a library providing a systematical solution to easily get the monitor info, like cpu load, mem status and so on.

Comment: "Use subprocess to call another process that can get this information for you."----->I don't understand your meaning, you mean what process can I use subprocess to call to get the monitor info?

Comment: `top` gets the CPU usage, `free` gets the memory details and so on. But PyMeter is better. I suggested subprocess in case you didn't want to use a library, but since you are OK with it, PyMeter does the job.

Comment: OK, I've knew what you mean,Thank you very much, It's very helpful!But besides PyMeter, is there any library else?From the PyMeter's document, the pymether does not moniter by "agent", PyMeter does not require special permissions or anything to be installed on the host that is being monitored. It connects using standard remote connection methods (TELNET or SSH) and runs native system tools to gather stats. Is there some monitoring by "angent"?

Comment: PyMeter should do what you want, I am not aware of any other library. PyMeter just works!

Comment: Thanks for your suggesstion, I'll take in it deeply~~

Answer (score 1):

Like Sukhbir suggested earlier, you can look beyond python by using subprocess to invoke another tool that can do this for you. Look at Dstat. It returns a very large number of metrics in easily digestible format, and might just suit your needs.

The Dtat homepage -
http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/dstat/

Comment: I've got the Dstat suits this scene, but I don't find a way to call the dstat directly except catching the output of the cmdline, how can I use it more directly and more gracefully?  Thank you~